# Why is my simple_fields_for not iterating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have the following (simplified) classes:

```
class CandidateList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :candidates, inverse_of: :candidate_list, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :candidate_list, inverse_of: :candidates
  ...
end
```

In my controller, I create a `CandidateList` with 10 `Candidate` objects and querying the database verifies that they exist and are attached.

In my form, I've got the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for save_bingo_terms_path( candidate_list_id: @candidate_list ) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= @candidate_list.candidates.count %>
  <table>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :candidates do |cf| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= cf.input :name, label: false %></td>
      <td><%= cf.input :definition, label: false %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone help me understand why it only shows me a single row in the table with an input field for `name` and `definition` even though the `count` output above the table shows `10`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:candidates` is not associated with the @candidate_list object, it's associated with a `save_bingo_terms_path`

Change the `simple_form_for` to

```
<%= simple_form_for @candidate_list do |f| %>
```

And don't forget to specify...

```
class CandidateList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :candidates, inverse_of: :candidate_list, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :candidates
  ...
end
```

Alternatively you can explicitly specify an `each` loop and reference each candidate

```
<% @candidate_list.candidates each do |candidate| %>
  <% f.simple_fields_for :candidates, candidate do |cf| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= cf.input :name, label: false %></td>
      <td><%= cf.input :definition, label: false %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think that's it. One of these days, I have to read more about FormBuilders... For now, I think I'm just going to flip this over to being a resource.